# $P(X \geq 7 \mid X > 1)$ given a distribution $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I need to calculate the chance something keeps working after 7 "days" (given it works already for a day); Where there chance for failure per day ($x$ in days) is given by the distribution:
$$f(x) = \frac{2}{(x+1)^3}$$
with $x \geq 0$

First steps are trivial but given here for completeness:

$$P(X \geq 7 \mid X > 1) = \frac{P (X \geq 7 \cap X > 1)}{P(X > 1)} = \frac{P(X \geq 7)}{P(X>1)} \\ = \frac{1 - P(X < 7)}{1 - P(X < 1} = \frac{F(7)}{F(1)}$$

With $F(X)$ bein the cumulative distribution function:

$$ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{2}{(x+1)^3} dx$$
$$ F(x) = \left. -\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right|_{-\infty}^x = -\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$

Now here my calculation crashed hard: $F(1)$ and $F(7)$ would be smaller than zero: that seems illogical and mistaken - a negative chance? Did I miss a simple trick? Did I calculate some part wrong?

Comment: If $f_X(x) = 2(x+1)^{-3}$ for $x \ge 0$, then $\Pr[X \le x] = F_X(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$, suggesting that the lower bound of the interval of integration should be $0$, not $-\infty$ as you wrote.

Comment: Always pay attention to the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just made mistakes with calculations. We have for $x\ge 0$
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\mathrm{Pr}(X\ge 7|X>1)=\frac{\mathrm{Pr}(X\ge 7)}{\mathrm{Pr}(X>1)}=\frac{1-F(7)}{1-F(1)}=\frac{1}{16}.
$$